# How to select from relational database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am starting to learn how databases work and I have always had all my data in one table. I am looking over an open-source project which I would like to create an interface for and the database structure is too complicated for me to understand.

I am sure it has a relational database structure (if I have learned properly). This is what the database structure looks like:

```
-- Table structure for table `databasechangelog`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `databasechangelog` (
  `ID` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `AUTHOR` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `FILENAME` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `DATEEXECUTED` datetime NOT NULL,
  `ORDEREXECUTED` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `EXECTYPE` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `MD5SUM` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DESCRIPTION` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENTS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TAG` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LIQUIBASE` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CONTEXTS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LABELS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Table structure for table `databasechangeloglock`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `databasechangeloglock` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LOCKED` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `LOCKGRANTED` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOCKEDBY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Table structure for table `devices`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `devices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `uniqueid` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastupdate` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `positionid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_device_uniqueid` (`uniqueid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Table structure for table `positions`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `positions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `protocol` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deviceid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `servertime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `devicetime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `fixtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `valid` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `latitude` double NOT NULL,
  `longitude` double NOT NULL,
  `altitude` float NOT NULL,
  `speed` float NOT NULL,
  `course` float NOT NULL,
  `address` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
  `attributes` varchar(4096) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `position_deviceid_fixtime` (`deviceid`,`fixtime`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=145 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Table structure for table `server`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `server` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `registration` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'1',
  `latitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `longitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `zoom` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `map` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `distanceunit` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `speedunit` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bingkey` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mapurl` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `readonly` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Table structure for table `users`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `hashedpassword` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `readonly` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `admin` bit(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT b'0',
  `map` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'osm',
  `language` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en',
  `distanceunit` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'km',
  `speedunit` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'kmh',
  `latitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `longitude` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `zoom` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uk_user_email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
-- Table structure for table `user_device`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_device` (
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `deviceid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `fk_user_device_deviceid` (`deviceid`),
  KEY `user_device_user_id` (`userid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `positions`
--
ALTER TABLE `positions`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_position_deviceid` FOREIGN KEY (`deviceid`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

--
-- Constraints for table `user_device`
--
ALTER TABLE `user_device`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_device_deviceid` FOREIGN KEY (`deviceid`) REFERENCES `devices` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_user_device_userid` FOREIGN KEY (`userid`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

When a user registers, it adds an entry to the "users" table and the user gets an id.

Then when the user adds a device, the user_device table looks like this:

[image]

And the devices table looks like this:

[image]

This is a GPS tracking software, so each device then posts it's position in the "positions" table which looks like this:

[image]

So, if a user logs in, how do I query the positions table and get all info from all devices of that user? I am assuming I would need to join the tables but I don't know how to do that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a relational database but it's not a normalised one. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's build it incrementally.  First, what is the actual data you want?

> query the positions table

Ok, start with that:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  positions
```

Now how do you want to further filter that data?

> from all devices of that user

Ok, so we need to relate this table (`positions`) through devices and to the user.  So ultimately we'll need a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
WHERE
  userid = ?
```

But `positions` doesn't have a `userid`, so let's walk through joining some tables until we have one.  `positions` *does* have a `deviceid`, so we can join that:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  positions
  INNER JOIN devices
    ON positions.deviceid = devices.id
```

We still don't have a `userid`, though.  And `devices` itself doesn't reference anything to further help us.  But there's a table which *does* reference `devices`, `user_device`.  Let's join that:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  positions
  INNER JOIN devices
    ON positions.deviceid = devices.id
  INNER JOIN user_device
    ON devices.id = user_device.deviceid
```

You'll see that we're getting a lot of data now.  But you'll also see that we're now getting a `userid` column, so we can finally add our `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  positions
  INNER JOIN devices
    ON positions.deviceid = devices.id
  INNER JOIN user_device
    ON devices.id = user_device.deviceid
WHERE
  userid = ?
```

At this point we should be getting all of the unique `positions` from any `device` related to that `user`.  You can get *just* the `position` data by replacing `SELECT *` with `SELECT positions.*`, or you can explicitly define which columns from which tables you want to select.

Comment: You, Sir, are awesome :) I have read through so many articles but I still didn't quite understand it but your concise and patient explanation did the trick! It makes so much sense and I see the logic behind the query now. Thanks for explaining it to me like I am 5 years old, given the fact that i'm 11, this was exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Bruno: You're very welcome.  I highly encourage you to execute the individual queries here and see how the results change with each step.  Try joining other tables and see what that does as well.  A `SELECT` by itself can't hurt the data, so get creative :)

Answer (score 0):

it would appear from your notes that you know when the user logs in which device he has. if this is correct, you should not need a join. Just do a select on the positions table where the positions.deviceid = the login device.